# Is there a way to take a list of SNPs and find which ones fall under histone modification peaks in R?

Tags: r

If I have a bed files containing histone modification data and a file containing SNPs how do I find which of those SNPs fall under the histone modification peaks, in R [Preferably without having to do it manually]?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired output. Don't forget to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: The `bedr` package can certianly do this, maybe have a look here and edit the question if you are still having problems? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bedr